# Qualifier spanning a aggregate tree

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I would like to create multiple instances of a CDI bean and further down the aggregate tree select implementation of an interface depending on a qualifier.

In the following example I create two instances of Controller with a qualifier. The controller is a part of a core library which contains a number of classes in our case. I would like to be able to select different implementations of Repository for the two different Controllers depending on the qualifier.

I could create a @Producer to select between the two Repository implementations but I can’t figure out how to determine which instance to return. I have no access to the qualifier specified at the injection point of the Controller but only the injection point of the Repository.

Currently we have the two Repository implementations living in different war’s with a dependency to the core lib which solved the problem but I would like to be able to change that.

### Application

```java
class MyApplication {
    @Inject
    @Component("comp1")
    Controller controller1;

    @Inject
    @Component("comp2")
    Controller controller2;
}

@Component("comp1")
public class Comp1Repository implements Repository {

}

@Component("comp2")
public class Comp2Repository implements Repository {

}
```

### Core library

```java
public interface Repository {

}

public class Controller {
    @Inject
    Repository repository;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you want.  Would this work?

```
@Produces
@Component("comp1")
@Dependent // or whatever scope you need
private Controller makeAppropriateController(@Component("comp1") final Repository comp1Repository) {
  return makeController(comp1Repository); // however you do it
}

@Produces
@Component("comp2")
@Dependent // or whatever scope you need
private Controller makeAppropriateController(@Component("comp2") final Repository comp2Repository) {
  return makeController(comp2Repository); // however you do it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes that would work for the example, unfortunately i have simplified the example. In the real case there may be any number of aggregate beans between the Controller and the Repository.

Comment: You may then be interested in https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/dynamic-cdi-producer-methods/